# SQL to only return the top x rows

Tags: sql, grouping, greatest-n-per-group

On our ticketing system, I want to export the names of the people who raise the most tickets for each customer, but only the top 2 for each customer.

In simple terms, a table called `Tickets`:

| TicketNo | Customer | Person |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | JoeTrading | Bob |
| 1235 | JoeTrading | Bob |
| 1236 | SmallShop | Jimmy |
| 1237 | BigSupplies | Jane |
| 1238 | JoeTrading | Gemma |
| 1239 | BigSupplies | Jane |
| 1240 | JoeTrading | Gemma |
| 1241 | BigSupplies | Jane |
| 1242 | SmallShop | Jimmy |
| 1243 | BigSupplies | Jane |
| 1244 | JoeTrading | Megan |
| 1245 | BigSupplies | Jane |

In the above example, I want to return:
*Customer Name, Person, Count of ticket No*

But only return the top 2 counts of ticket no for each customer. i.e. Joe Trading would only return Bob and Gemma because they're the top 2, and Megan would be hidden.

I've tried this, but it's wrong

```
select CUSTOMER, Person, count() 
from Tickets
group by CUSTOMER_NAME
```

> Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> The count function requires 1 argument(s).

Comment: Customer needs to be spelt the same and count needs a column, what are you counting? count('ticketNumber')

Comment: Please add the expected result to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
SELECT Customer, Person, Count
FROM (
   SELECT 
      Customer, 
      Person, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT TicketNo) AS Count,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY COUNT(TicketNo) DESC ) as R
   from Tickets 
   GROUP BY Customer,Person
) x 
WHERE R<=2
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

results:

| Customer | Person | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BigSupplies | Jane | 5 |
| JoeTrading | Bob | 2 |
| SmallShop | Jimmy | 2 |
| JoeTrading | Megan | 1 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/GPM1MMSS)  (extended from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75759722/724039))

Comment: Hi @Luuk
That doesn't seem to show me the top 2 for each customer, based on the count of the ticket no?

Comment: @RobCross You just need to change the sort direction for the ROW_NUMBER [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/87oomTSZ)

Comment: oops, added the `DESC`.  I overlooked because of not enough test data 

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try this to count the number of TicketNo per customer:

```
SELECT Customer, COUNT(DISTINCT TicketNo) AS Count from Tickets GROUP BY Customer;
```

I use DISTINCT to make sure the tickets are not counted more than once if there are duplicated entries of TicketNo in the Tickets table. Though, this command will not be able to keep the top 2 counts of TicketNo for each customer.

Note: I previously used SELECT TOP 2 to keep the top 2 counts of TicketNo for each customer, but as Luuk pointed out, this does not work as expected. Better to refer to Luuk's answer, which is more comprehensive.

Comment: When the `group by` is corrected, you only get 2 lines in the result (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/WmoUBuQb )

Comment: Hi Luuk, this is helpful, thank you! I will modify my answer a bit and refer to your answer, which is more comprehensive.